# ffmpeg and libx264 videos do not play on video player

Tags: video, ffmpeg

for a few months now I encountered a problem using `FFmpeg` in combination with the video code `h264`. The video generation works fine and without any errors. I am using the following script since 2015 to build my videos from single pictures:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                                                                               
# Video generator                                                               
# Tobias Holzmann                                                               
# Date: 18.03.15                                                                
# Update: 24.12.2019                                                            
# Switch back to ffmpeg from avconv                                             
#                                                                               
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

frameRate=30                                                                    
vcodec="h264"                                                                   
crf=18              # Between 0-51; 23 is default. 0 = lossless                 


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ffmpeg \                                                                        
    -f image2 \                                                                 
    -r $frameRate \                                                             
    -i animation.%4d.png \                                                      
    -r $frameRate \                                                             
    -crf $crf \                                                                 
    -vcodec $vcodec \                                                           
    AVideo.flv                                                                  


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Today I made it a bit more fancy and easier to use. However, the problem is, that all videos I generate with `h264` do not play at all using the `vlc` player or the common Ubuntu video player. I get errors such as:

```
shorty@animation: vlc AVideo.flv 
VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[000055c0e70af420] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[NULL @ 0x7fe318c2c2a0] Invalid NAL unit size (30490 > 15039).
[NULL @ 0x7fe318c2c2a0] missing picture in access unit with size 15733
[h264 @ 0x7fe318c2c2a0] Invalid NAL unit size (30490 > 15039).
[h264 @ 0x7fe318c2c2a0] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
[00007fe324c1c420] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  430.50  Thu Sep  5 22:38:52 CDT 2019 for hardware decoding
[h264 @ 0x7fe325428ac0] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324c1fb00] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324eb9d80] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324ed6080] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324ef2400] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324f0e780] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe325428ac0] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324c1fb00] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324eb9d80] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324ed6080] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[h264 @ 0x7fe324ef2400] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
[00007fe324c1c420] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[h264 @ 0x7fe324f0e780] hardware accelerator failed to decode picture
...
...
```

I am wondering if someone does know where the problem is located. Any hint or feedback is appreciated. Thank you in advance and kind regards, Tobi.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: You are getting "hardware accelerator failed" errors (related to NVIDIA decoder). Try disabling hardware accelerator in VLC player.

Comment: @Rotem  , this is the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of just disabling hardware accelerator, try updating your GPU driver (the GPU acceleration feature requires driver support).

Comment: For me, this program just started happening without apparent cause and other programs were able to use the AMD GPU just fine. Setting Tools→Preferences→Input/Codecs→Hardware-accelerated decoding from the default "Automatic" to either "VA-API decoder" or "VA-API decoder via DRM" or "Disabled" fixed the issue, but "VDPAU video decoder" did not, so that one was probably selected by the automatic mode. Installing "libvdpau-va-gl" did not fix this either. So I just switched to "VA-API decoder". This is very likely not the same issue for you, because you have a NVidia GPU,but Google brought me here.